# Classic Editor text font color is white after installing the latest version of wordpress

Tags: editor

I've updated the latest WordPress to the latest version and installed the classic editor for the editor. But when switch to the text mode font shows in white color.

Comment: It's better you enable the `WP_DEBUG` in your WordPress to see the current error.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Comment: I've enabled WP_DEBUG, But no issues found

Comment: It' seems there are inline CSS in your theme or WordPress and you can see that with Inspect in your browser.

Comment: Yes, when I inspected the font is white as mentioned in the question. the css is  .js .tmce-active .wp-editor-area {
   color: #fff; 
}
 this makes the font color white

Comment: Try my answer :)

Comment: I've tried in different browsers .but not working

Answer (score 0):

Add below new constant in your `wp-config.php`

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

If the cache enabled in your WordPress, try to clear the cache.

Comment: Did you this method?
@aparna-mathew